# Shutdown VM Host if Data store is lost

Tags: virtualization

Hi i have 2 virtual cisco apps on 2 seperate servers that are HBA connected to a vnx datastore – when i lose the connections to the datastore my LUN becomes inactive on the corresponding host . Is there a way I can set up an alert so that if the LUN becomes inactive then it will close down the corresponding vmware host on that server. As soon as that host will shutdown then my other vmware host on the other server will become active. At the moment because the vmware host is still up (even though its datastore is not) its preventing the other machine to become active – the redundancy is done in the cisco app rather than at vmware level. The HBA ‘s are dual connected with redundant switches so its very unlikely that the datastore will become disconnected but we have to test if it could happen.

I have tried putting an alert on the datastore with a trigger of ‘unavailable to all hosts’ and an action of command ‘shutdown -h now’ but does not work. ..TIA, J

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up the redundancy using VMware's vMotion and vSphere High Availability (HA) instead.  What HA will do is automatically vMotion your VM to the other host upon detection of failure and allow it to continue with business as usual.

To solve your current problem I do not think it would be possible to do it with a simple shutdown of the host.  When a datastore becomes inaccessible then the VMs that are using that datastore go into a suspended state.  That would mean that the virtual Cisco app on that server would no longer function or respond.  If the Cisco part is doing the redundancy (with heartbeats between them or something) then the 2nd Cisco app should take over automatically regardless if the other host is online or not.  The Cisco app does not know that it is a virtual machine running on a host.

Also, if you are running `shutdown -h [hibernation]` with the intent of shutting down the VM on the host that no longer has a connection the datastore, that will not work either.  Since the VM goes into a suspended state and the datastore isn't available there is no place for the VM to store the hiberation file.

If you are trying to shutdown the host, you will be best to use a vSphere PowerCLI script if possible and use `Stop-VMHost` cmdlets.  See reference [**here**](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Stop-VMHost.html).  Also, keep in mind that to run the PowerCLI scripts you must put it on a different machine or VM than the one on the host you are shutting down.

Here is how you run PowerCLI scripts from the alarms:
http://blogs.vmware.com/vipowershell/2009/09/how-to-run-powercli-scripts-from-vcenter-alarms.html

Comment: Vote++.  HA is the way to go.